# How can I add a unique ID to each dynamic blockquote?

Tags: javascript, html

`` ` ``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SRT to Prose Converter</title>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    
</head>
<body class="container py-5">

<h1 class="fs-3 mb-4">SRT to Prose Converter</h1>

<div class="card mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="file" accept=".srt" class="form-control" id="srt-file-input">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="convert-button">Convert</button>
        </div>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Please select an SRT file.</small>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="fs-4 mb-4">Parsing Results</h2>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="output-tabs" role="tablist">
         
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <button class="nav-link active" id="sertd-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#sertd-tab-content" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="sertd-tab-content" aria-selected="false">
                   srt file
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="output-tabs-content">
        
           
            <div class="tab-pane fade bg-light p-3 border rounded show active" id="sertd-tab-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sertd-tab">
            
                <p class="mb-0 alert alert-warning">Please select an SRT file.</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add Bootstrap 5 JS and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>


    const pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage = 'Please select an SRT file.';
    const pleaseSelectSrtFile = '<p class="alert alert-warning mb-0">' + pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage + '</p>';

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#srt-file-input').change(function () {
            const file = $('#srt-file-input').prop('files')[0];
            if (file && file.name.endsWith('.srt')) {
                $('.form-text').html(file.name);
            } else {
                $('.form-text').html(pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage);
            }
        });

        $('#convert-button').click(function () {
            const file = $('#srt-file-input').prop('files')[0];
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    const subtitles = parseSrt(event.target.result);
                    let sertd = generatesertdView(subtitles);
                    $('#sertd-tab-content').html(sertd);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            } else {
              
                $('#sert-tab-content').html(pleaseSelectSrtFile);
            }
        });
    });


    function parseSrt(srt) {
    
        const subtitleBlocks = srt.trim().split(/\n\s*\n/);
        const subtitles = subtitleBlocks.map(subtitleBlock => {
          
            let [timeString, ...textLines] = subtitleBlock.split("\n");
            
            vtr = timeString
            timeString = textLines[0];
            textLines.shift(); // remove index
            const [startTimeString, endTimeString] = timeString.split(" --> ");
            const text = textLines
            const translate = text
            
                .join("\n")
                .replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")
                .replace(/\{.*?\}/g, '')
            return {
            vtr,
                startTimeString,
                endTimeString,
                text,
            translate
            };
        });
        return subtitles;
    }

    
      function generatesertdView(subtitles) {
        const paragraphsd = subtitles.map(subtitle =>  `<blockquote contenteditable="true"> <p>${ subtitle.vtr +"<br>" +subtitle.startTimeString  + "  -->  " + subtitle.endTimeString +"<br>" + subtitle.text+"<br><br>"}</p></blockquote>`);
 

const sertd = document.createElement('myBlackquote')
sertd.innerHTML = paragraphsd.join('\n')
document.body.append(sertd)

        return sertd;
        
    

    }


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

When import the srt file Somehow it does the whole file in three parts Then blockquote dozens of times Is it possible Let's add an ID for Eche blockquote want to I'll copy it   Each one separately All in one way?
submit button.

Answer (score 0):

In your function where you generate the HTML tags, just create an ID for it.  the `map` method has a 2nd parameter that's an index, so you can leverage that

```js
function generatesertdView(subtitles) {
  const paragraphsd = subtitles.map((subtitle, idx) =>
    `<blockquote id="subtitle-${idx}" contenteditable="true">
      <p>${ subtitle.vtr +"<br>" +subtitle.startTimeString  + "  -->  " + subtitle.endTimeString +"<br>" + subtitle.text+"<br><br>"}</p>
     </blockquote>`);

  const sertd = document.createElement('myBlackquote')
  sertd.innerHTML = paragraphsd.join('\n')
  document.body.append(sertd)

  return sertd;
}
```

---

This is unrelated to your question but keep in mind that `document.createElement('myBlackquote')` will create an `<myBlackquote></myBlackquote>` element.  I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do or not, but this is not a real or standard HTML element.

A better way to do this would be to create a standard element, and then give it an ID, like this:

```js
const sertd = document.createElement('div');
sertd.id = 'myBlackquote'
sertd.innerHTML = paragraphsd.join('\n')
```

That will result in `<div id="myBlackquote"></div>`

Comment: #chris Bar Thank you dear for your reply
  I've put again what I work here again.
  Can you help me?                                                                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469983/how-copy-multiple-dynamic-blockquote-from-original-text-list-to-copy-original

Comment: @rebazfaisal If my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer to your question