# how copy multiple dynamic blockquote from "original text" list to "copy original text" list on one click submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have prepared the project
Somehow it only copies one
I want him to copy it all
With one click of the submit button
When import the srt file Somehow it does the whole file in two parts
Is that impossible or possible.
This is a new question but relates [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131501/add-a-column-to-a-table-generated-by-jquery-function-from-csv/48131930?noredirect=1#comment83254494_48131930). In short, I am now able to copy a cell in a generated table to the clipboard. What I would like to do now is add more text to the clipboard using the same button. I have tried using the imperative API as the [docs](https://clipboardjs.com/) suggest but I can still only copy the original target. How do I copy multiple elements using clipboard.js with one button click?

```js
const pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage = 'Please select an SRT file.';
const pleaseSelectSrtFile = '<p class="alert alert-warning mb-0">' + pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage + '</p>';

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#srt-file-input').change(function () {
    const file = $('#srt-file-input').prop('files')[0];
    if (file && file.name.endsWith('.srt')) {
      $('.form-text').html(file.name);
    } else {
      $('.form-text').html(pleaseSelectSrtFileMessage);
    }
  });

  $('#convert-button').click(function () {
    const file = $('#srt-file-input').prop('files')[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (event) {
          const subtitles = parseSrt(event.target.result);

          let table = generateTableView(subtitles);
          $('#table-tab-content').html(table);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
      $('#table-tab-content').html(pleaseSelectSrtFile);
    }
  });
});

function parseSrt(srt) {
  const subtitleBlocks = srt.trim().split(/\n\s*\n/);
  const subtitles = subtitleBlocks.map(subtitleBlock => {
      let [timeString, ...textLines] = subtitleBlock.split("\n");

      vtr = timeString
      timeString = textLines[0];
      textLines.shift(); // remove index
      const [startTimeString, endTimeString] = timeString.split(" --> ");
      const text = textLines
          .join("\n")
          .replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")
          .replace(/\{.*?\}/g, '')
      return { vtr, text };
  });
  return subtitles;
}

function generateTableView(subtitles) {
    const z = "copy text ";
    const rows = subtitles.map((subtitle, idx) => `
    <td><blockquote id="subtitle-${idx }"contenteditable="true" contenteditable="true"><p>${subtitle.text}</p></blockquote></td>
    <td><blockquote id="subtitle-${subtitle.vtr }"  contenteditable="true"><p>${z+subtitle.vtr }</p> </p></blockquote></td>
    </tr>`);
    const table = `<table class="rebaz table " border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Orignal Text</th>
    <th>copy Orignal Text</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ${rows.join('')}
    </tbody>
    </table>`;
    
    return table;
}

function transferData() {
  // Get the content of the first blockquote
  var content1 = document.getElementById('subtitle-0').innerText;

  // Set the content of the second blockquote
  document.getElementById('subtitle-1').innerText = content1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body class="container py-5">
  <h1 class="fs-3 mb-4">SRT to Prose Converter</h1>

  <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="file" accept=".srt" class="form-control" id="srt-file-input">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="convert-button">Convert</button>
          </div>
          <small class="form-text text-muted">Please select an SRT file.</small>
      </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="fs-4 mb-4">Parsing Results</h2>

  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="output-tabs" role="tablist">

              <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                  <button class="nav-link active" id="table-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#table-tab-content" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="table-tab-content" aria-selected="false">
                      Table View
                  </button>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content" id="output-tabs-content">


              <div class="tab-pane fade bg-light p-3 border rounded show active" id="table-tab-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="table-tab">
                  <p class="mb-0 alert alert-warning">Please select an SRT file.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="transferData()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy anything into the clipboard, you don't need to use a library like clipboard.js. There is a [native clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) supported well by most modern browsers.  You just give it a string of text to put into the clipboard.  That string can be HTML if you want.

```js
const tableEl = document.querySelector('table');

function textToClipboard(str){
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(str).then(
    () => console.log('String sucessfully copied to clipboard!'),
    () => console.log('String FAILED to be copied to clipboard!'),
  );
}


document.querySelector('#btn-copyText').addEventListener('click', () => {
  textToClipboard(tableEl.innerText)
});

document.querySelector('#btn-copyHtml').addEventListener('click', () => {
  textToClipboard(tableEl.innerHTML)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container py-4">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-copyText">Copy table TEXT to clipboard</button>
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-copyHtml">Copy table HTML to clipboard</button>
  <hr>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Letter</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```